# Force Amazon S3 to send Access-Control-Allow-Origin header by default

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers

S3 response me `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header only if send to him `Origin` and `Access-Control-Request-Method`. Is there way that S3 will response `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` by default, without any special headers?

Comment: I have the same problem, because edgecast cdn caches the response headers that it receives from amazon. if the first request for the file does not recevie the headers, then future requests, which may need the headers, will fail

Comment: I you what force the header because CloudFront cache it you can slave it via:  "Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS): You can now configure Amazon CloudFront to cache content based on the Origin Header. This means Amazon CloudFront will respect any CORS rules that your origin server has set up to provide access to the websites you want." https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/06/26/amazon-cloudfront-device-detection-geo-targeting-host-header-cors/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [W3C CORS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests), the CORS response headers should only be included if the request contains an `Origin` header.

S3 follows this spec so it's not possible to force it to always send the CORS response headers.